# Using Parse REST API backend for session management without client-side SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, session, express

I'm writing my app's server to use Parse.com's REST API with Express. My client-side is to get apart from Parse JavaScript SDK and let everything be handled on server-side only, including session management. So I have to write server code so as to validate all client requests without any usage of client-side Parse SDK. I don't know where to start from? Or just simply drop Parse.com and make better use of other Node modules such as `express-session`?

Comment: "When user logs in on client-side" -  you mean to say user is logging in or getting authenticated through other backend service rather then yours? I mean how do you know user is logged in and authenticated? How do you know who is this user?

Comment: @SkArif Thanks. You remind me of my prequisite issue... I changed the question

Comment: @SkArif Actually, when I posted this question, what I meant "logging in" is sending a request with `username` and `password` to server to get authenticated. Then my server conducts authenticating with `username` and `password` from message

Comment: Then I would say use `express-session`. There is also a session handler developed by **mozilla** called [`client-session`](https://github.com/mozilla/node-client-sessions). It has some nice feature built in. But if you want to keep things minimal `express-session` is best.